# Need some help on linear algebra Subspace test

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ${\bf a)}$

Note that $(t,-t\sin(\pi/3),\sqrt{2}t)+(s,-s\sin(\pi/3),\sqrt{2}s)=(t+s,-(t+s)\sin(\pi/3),\sqrt{2}(t+s))\in W$ and $\alpha (t,-t\sin(\pi/3),\sqrt{2})=(\alpha t,-\alpha t\sin(\pi/3),\sqrt{2}\alpha t)\in W.$ Thus, $W$ is a linear subspace.

To ${\bf b)}$

Note that $\vec{u}=(1,0,0),\vec{v}=(0,1,1)\in W.$ However $$\vec{u}+\vec{v}=(1,1,1)\notin W.$$ Thus, it is not a linear subspace.

To ${\bf c)}$

If $f,g\in V$ is it $(f+g)(2)=(f+g)(-2)?$ Is it $(\alpha f)(2)=(\alpha f)(-2)?$

Answer (score 0):

For $1(b)$ you are wrong

$(1,2,0) ,(0,2,3)\in W$ but $(1,4,3)\notin W$

For $1(c)$

let $f,g \in W$ then $(f+g)(2)=f(2)+g(2)=f(-2)+g(-2)=(f+g)(-2)$

Also for any $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ ($\lambda f)(2)=\lambda f(2)=\lambda f(-2)=(\lambda f)(-2)$